# Browsers KB/s is 1000 or 1024 bytes per second?

Tags: networking, byte

As you probably know a Kilobyte might refer to 1000 bytes or to 1024 bytes, depending on the context. More info on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte).

Most browsers express download speed in KB/s.

**Question**: do you know if they are using the 1000 or the 1024 convention for that Kilobyte? If you know about a specific browser (i.e., Firefox or Chrome) that will help already.

I am asking cause I am working on an application that needs to measure download speeds accurately, and this would help with the comparison.

Comment: You should of looked at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Prefix:_k_vs_Ki) Wikipedia page instead. Having said that, you cant rely on the text, and would be much better off hooking into some system level information of what volume of data an application is recieving/transmitting over the network card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Preet Kukreti for pointing me in the right direction. According [to this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Prefix%3a_k_vs_Ki) the answer is 1000 bytes.

So KB/s on browsers means 1000 bytes per second, not 1024.

Comment: depends on whether they're using units correctly or not, which is unique to each browser (or even components within a certain browser).